# Third party login NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

My friend wants me to create a bid - sniper app for him for a specific website
So How can I achieve the feature where user can login on that app through my app?
What technologies and concept do I have to use?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use node.js Puppeteer library (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to login. Here is some example code https://docs.apify.com/tutorials/log-into-a-website-using-puppeteer#find-the-login-form